# How to make the child Elements vertically in the middle of the parent with css?

Tags: css, web

How to make the child  Elements in the middle of the parent vertically automatically Whatever change parent's height  with css

.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    parent{ 
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Hamid. I have been searching for the way for days. God bless you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```css
.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: beige;
   height: 400px;
 }
 .child {
   background-color: aqua;
   flex: auto;
   text-align: center;
   height: 200px;
   display: inherit;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">this is a test</div>
  <div class="child">this is a test</div>
  <div class="child">this is a test</div>

</div>
```

You can use flex..

Here is Html Code and change the code according to your needs:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">this is a test</div>
   <div class="child">this is a test</div>
   <div class="child">this is a test</div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS Code

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: beige;
   height: 400px;
 }
 .child {
   background-color: aqua;
   flex: auto;
   text-align: center;
   height: 200px;
   display: inherit;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 10px;
 }
```

thank you ;)

Answer (score -3):

First: share your code's please
Second: Use `margin: auto 0;`.
Third: its duplicate: [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div/45251566#45251566)